# Comparing 2 objects with '==' returning True when the objects are at different memory addesses (objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, pointers, equality

I have a custom object (Artist) which is an NSManagedObject subclass (it's one of the entities in my Core Data database).

The following 2 properties are declared on an Artist object:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *artworks;
```

When comparing two artist objects ('selectedArtist' and 'artist'), the following appears to perform a deep equality comparison even though it's only comparing pointers. It returns true when the two Artist objects have the same 'name' and 'artworks' even though they are at different memory addresses:

```
if (selectedArtist == artist) {
    NSLog(@"found equal artists");
    NSLog(@"Selected artist named: %@ located at: %p", selectedArtist.name, &selectedArtist);
    NSLog(@"Other artist named: %@ located at: %p", artist.name, &artist);
}
```

Output for 2 Artist objects with same 'name' and 'artworks':

"found equal artists

Selected artist named: artist1 located at: 0x175a80e8

Other artist named: artist1 located at: 0x1716bc"

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? I can provide more info if this isn't sufficient.

Comment: Your 3rd `NSLog` statement is wrong. You have one format specifier but two arguments. The 2nd argument will be ignored. Get rid of `artist.name` in the `NSLog` and then update your question with the results.

Comment: BTW - what do the two variables used in the `if` statement have to do with the two properties? They seem completely unrelated.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry yes, I'm paraphrasing the actual code. I've edited that out. in the real code the NSLog statement displays multiple variables. The 2 variables are 2 'Artist' objects I'm comparing. The if statement, simply using == is somehow performing a deep equality comparison (it says they're equal because their instance variables are the same even though at different memory addresses)

Comment: Post REAL code. There's no point in helping debug "paraphrased" code. It's different and won't have the same issues as the actual code giving you issues.

Comment: And this is now absolutely 100 % copy and paste from your working code?

Answer (score 1):

You are logging something completely meaningless and are confused by it.

You have two variables, selectedArtist and artist, both pointing to the same object. That's what "==" compares. But you are logging the addresses of the variables. Of course you get different results, because there are two different variables.

```
int x = 5;
int y = 5;

if (x == y) {
    NSLog (@"%p %p", &x, &y); // Not tested
}
```

Do you expect &x and &y to be the same? Of course not. You just got yourself totally confused and are jumping to the wrong conclusion. You have two variables pointing to the same object, so the variables compare equal, and of course name and artwork will compare equal, because they are the name and artwork are the same.

Comment: oh yes I see what you're saying... if I remove the 2 '&' symbols in my NSLog statements, then they show the same address. I was looking at the address of the pointer itself as you mentioned. Need to go back and review pointers and memory! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know what you are asking. The thing is you can't just compare objects using "==", it doesn't work that way. Apple has designated comparators for this stuff. You really should post what your custom NSManagedObject looks like but even without that, and since these are NSSets, the following should work:

```
if ([[selectedArtist artworks] isEqualToSet:[artist artworks]]) {
    //do work
}
```

you could also convert the NSSet to an Array and compare arrays, you can also compare the NSString "name" assuming this code will correspond to your managed object.

```
if ([[selectedArtist name] isEqualToString:[artist name]]) {
  //do work
}
```

Here's the info you wanted based on the comments below. First off, "==" compares pointers, which I guess is weird because you show the pointers being the same. It looks like NSManagedObjects can be compared with "==" just fine, it's only certain NSObjects that can't be compared that way, very interesting.

Read here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-223939

Read here:

http://nshipster.com/equality/

Comment: sorry maybe my wording was unclear. I am aware of == not working that way, which is why I am so surprised that it DID work in this case. This is what I am asking, how come it is working for me on 2 objects that are at different memory addresses?

Comment: How many comparisons have you tried? I would suspect that perhaps it returns "true" for all combos if it's returning true for "1 example", unless of course you are seeing that it's returning "FALSE" when the artist doesn't match the selectedArtist. If it continues to work, then you my friend, just discovered something as awesome as cold fusion, because it shouldn't work!

Comment: Correct, it is returning false when the 'name' and 'artworks' property are not equal between the 2 objects. Very strange behaviour. If there's no simple answer I may have made some other error elsewhere?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd say, there's no reason why it would report as TRUE using the "==" comparator, that's strange, unless of course there's something weird with CLang or something that we don't see much of in ObjC. Does the comparison work with isEqualToSet? If that works and you verify that it works then that's a good start.

Comment: Here's the info you want, I'll post it above, looks like it makes sense sort of

Comment: Thanks!! I actually read through the NSHipster before posting the question and tried to overwrite isEqual: and hash: myself in my Artist object. The link to the Apple docs you posted explain why that was crashing my program. Is it saying that == for an NSManagedObject will compare the location of the 2 objects in the managed object context? Hence they are the same.

Comment: lol, yeah, after reading Mattt's stuff, I'm still super confused as to how you did what you did, it didn't help! It's still the same dumb problem of "==" relating to pointer equality and you got it to work for pointers that aren't pointing to the same thing, after I posted the stuff above, I said "this still doesn't make sense"